# Can the integrated Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core scan modules for dependencies?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a main ASP.NET Core Web Api project that consumes multiple projects but I follow the Clean Architecture, all interfaces are put in a core project, there are module projects (infrastructure) defining implementation. The main project just references the core project without knowing about the infrastructure.

That means we need to scan the modules for dependencies and auto-wire the implementation with the corresponding interfaces defined in the core project.

More specifically, suppose I have an interface IA (in core project) and an implementation A (in infrastructure), traditionally if the main project references both, we can just manually register the dependency like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
   services.AddTransient<IA, A>();
}
```

However with clean architecture, we just have `IA` available at design time, how can we scan and wire the implementation `A` in this case?

If that's not possible with the integrated Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core, I'd be interested in alternative solutions (such as `Autofac`). Still the trickiest part here is not registering manually but auto-wiring automatically (scanning).

Answer (score 1):

Create one more project called dependencyinjection, add the reference of interfaces and infrastructure and make it a composite root. In the second step give the reference of dependency injection to coreweb api and use your dependency injection in configureservices in startup.cs

Comment: thank you, well I think that way it changes the architecture fairly, I prefer to stick with the standard architecture. And really I know this is feasible, I just wonder about any possibility to play with just the integrated dependency injection in ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

The shell of your application (ASP.NET Core app, main project) depends on both Core and Infrastructure layers.  It is also your composition root where you build your service registrations.

Infrastructure - depends on Core

Shell (main prog) - depends on both core and Infrastructure

Your controllers use the abstractions in Core, but registrations in your composition root links the infrastructure to core.

Comment: I understand that (see my example code). But we don't strongly reference infrastructure projects in the main project by following ***clean architecture***. That's the point I'm asking about.

Comment: Refer to these GitHub project as an example of clean architecture https://github.com/ivanpaulovich/clean-architecture-manga/tree/master/template/content/Manga.WebApi and https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb/tree/master/src.  Notice that the shell project on both the core and infrastructure.  Do not over-complicate. Clean architecture is supposed to make your dependencies clearer

Comment: looks like you focus on the so-called ***infrastructure*** and gave your answer ignoring everything I've described clearly in my question. I don't want to reference all the implementation projects (that I call `Infrastructure projects`). There is just a misunderstanding (a difference between us) about the same word `infrastructure` here. And actually there are different understanding ways about that same word, I'm trying to find an article talking about that word in the way I understand and share it with you, but still not found yet.

Comment: here I've found it, you can reference this book https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb/blob/master/docs/Architecting%20Modern%20Web%20Applications%20with%20ASP.NET%20Core%20and%20Azure%20(v2.1).pdf  (from the same second link you shared with me above - eShopOnWeb). At page ***35*** you can see its introduction to Clean Architecture there, and here are the most important words extracted: `...both the UI and the Infrastructure layers depend on the Application Core, but
not on one another (necessarily)`

Comment: you can reference the infrastructure but that's not necessarily and in this case I want it that way.

Comment: What you've quoted means is the UI doesnt directly use the concrete implementations under the Infrastructure layer. You can follow akshay's suggestion to place the DI wire up in a separate project, but you still end up with reference to that DI proj which in turn references your infrastructure projs. The only thing you achieved is add a layer of indirection

Comment: No actually we have a much cleaner way, I know about that (something like MEF - Managed Extensibility Framework can do), and really Autofac supports that kind of scanning out of the box. But here I wonder if the integrated DI in ASP.NET Core can support that, and if not integration with Autofac is the way to go.

Comment: I guess to got too caught up with "clean architecture" i didn't see the essence of your question. AFAIK, MEF is what MS has out there for your case.